# Finbuckle: Should my DbContext inherit from MultiTenantIdentityDbContext or EFCoreStoreDbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant

I'm very new to Finbuckle, and still trying to get my head around it, so this may be a dumb question!

I want to build a multi-tenant application in ASP.NET Core, and intend to use a single-database approach.

To get me going, I followed the Identity sample, and so derived my DbContext from `MultiTenantIdentityDbContext` ([see here](https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/blob/main/samples/net6.0/IdentitySample/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs) for the sample code). To get me going, I hard-coded the tenants in `appSettings.json` like in that sample, but am now looking at picking them up from the database.

According to the [stores doc page](https://www.finbuckle.com/MultiTenant/Docs/v6.12.0/Stores), if I want to use the `EFCore Store`, my DbContext needs to inherit from `EFCoreStoreDbContext`.

I can't inherit from both, as C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, so how do I get around this?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Identity (Authentication/Authorization) is typically a separate `DbContext` instance than the `DbContext` that the application uses for data retrieval. I will commonly want references to users for things like CreatedBy/ModifiedBy etc. so the application DbContext can have a semblance (entity defined) for a User, but only exposing enough detail from the database table for that purpose. I.e. a lightweight User /w Id, Name, etc.

Comment: @StevePy Ah, that makes sense. As the tenant entity in our case is something that would be used in the regular code, I was thinking that we would just have the one dbcontext and have all data access go via that.

Answer (score 0):

To put it bluntly, you need to pick one or the other. Walk before you run

If either of them support an an Interface instead of concrete inheritance then you could implement that interface.